# listview Layout in android

Tags: android, layout

In my application i have 2 databases.My requirement is i have to show this 2 databases side by side in a single activity.I don't know exactly how much data is there in database.
Which way is easy for this?
Whether i should use Listview or a table Layout to get this.If it is listview means how can split the screen to show two databases(One more thing is i cant place 2 list views y because if i scroll the screen both the part should scroll).Anybody please help me.
I am looking for this for past 2 days,I cant get correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

If click event on basis of database value is not important you can use custom list view with with which you can display all values in single list

see this tutorial to make a custom list

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

and also

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android7dvancedListViewB.php#CustomListView

Edit

You can also use table layout ,

first do one thing fetch all the data from both the databases and as  per their size create one dynamic table layout on basis of bigger data set  and then fill the values in them .

Comment: Thanks Avi Kumar Manku.In the above link only i database display is like.But in my case i have display 2 databases side by side.

Comment: Use table layout ,i have just edited my answer , i did it when i was fetching values from two tables you can do the same

Answer (score 0):

So i suggest doing this:

1. put single ListView on your layout.
2. create layout for a cell.
3. create an invisible (Visibility = View.GONE) separator in upper part
   of a cell.
4. implement ListView adapter. ListView adapter defines content of a cell in all of the positions and looks like this

> ```
> public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
> {
>   @Override
>   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>                 /*CODE*/
>       return rowView;
>   }
> }
> ```

As you can see, you can place data from database 1 in rows 1-N and data from database 2 in rows N+1 - M.
You can also change the visiblity of your invisible separator to View.VISIBLE in order to create a separator between N and N+1.

Article on how to do all of this:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thanks Alehar.As i have specified in my question i don't want 2 or more list view.I want a single list view with separation in between them so i can so 2 databases,when i scroll the whole part will scroll.But in your answer it is more than 1 listview which means it will scroll separately.